# Cache is not disable on product page

Tags: magento2, block-cache

I am adding my custom block in product view page

xml

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block class="Company\Example\Block\Product\View\Type\Example" name="product.info.class.session"  before="-" template="product/view/type/options/example.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

I am trying to disable cache add `cacheable="false"` in xml its not working

than add this code in `__construct`

```
 $this->addData(
            [
                'cache_lifetime' => false
            ]
        );
```

this is also not working

than add this in `__construct`

```
$this->_isScopePrivate = true;
```

this is also not working.

how to disable cache is there any other way to disable cache for my custom block?

Comment: Did you try the following code ? `<block class="Company\Example\Block\Product\View\Type\Example" name="product.info.class.session"  before="-" template="product/view/type/options/example.phtml" cacheable="false" />`

Comment: Yes i tried this code